# How can I transfer data to the scanned bluetooth devices in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, data-transfer

I'm am new in Android development. How to transfer data to the scanned bluetooth devices in android?

Comment: Please search some before asking questions here on SO. It's understandable that you're new to both Android and SO, but it's a good practice to do your part of the work before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection) should help you to do what you desire. Given [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html) is a list of classes applicable for/on Bluetooth. Going through them in detail might help you in customizing your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DeepthiG Please click the Accept button if this answered your question!